# Best method to compare strings?

Tags: vb.net

Scenario: I created a software that calculates the hash of a file, and compares it to a hash list file in my possession (about 1 mln - growing), currently in txt format.
Which is the best way to make the comparison as fast as possibile?

I'm using this function:

```
Public HashList As New List(Of String)

Private Sub LoadHash()
   For Each hash As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\test\hash.txt")
      HashList.Add(hash)
   Next
End Sub

Private Function CheckFile(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
   If HashList.Contains(MD5(filename)) Then
      Return True
   End If

   Return False
End Function
```

Any suggestions for improve this code?
are there better methods?

Comment: Looking through a file with millions of hashes is not something that's easily optimized as it requires a lot of I/O and will be harder to fit in RAM as the file grows. Consider switching to a database instead.

Comment: I found another question in Python where the OP has benchmarked different methods of locating a string in a large text file. It might help you get some perspective on what you're up against :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/6219141

Comment: I don't know which one would be best put there are better collection to use. For example, if you had stored the hash in a dictionary, the search would be O(1) instead of O(n) from a list. Take a look at the [other type of collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.7.2). Maybe a HashSet

Comment: Is this an occasional one-off check? If so, you could have several files of the hashes with names like `"hash" & Math.Floor(Math.Log10(filesize + 1)) & ".txt"`. That way, there would be less data to read, which would be faster, and fewer items to look through, which would also be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a better collection type like a HashSet. [There are a lot in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.7.2) that all have their use.

```
Public HashList As New HashSet(Of String)
```