# subsetting very large files - python methods for optimal performance

Tags: python, performance, search, subset, large-files

I have one file (`index1`) with 17,270,877 IDs, and another file (`read1`) with a subset of these IDs (17,211,741).  For both files, the IDs are on every 4th line.

I need a new (`index2`) file that contains only the IDs in `read1`.  For each of those IDs I also need to grab the next 3 lines from `index1`. So I'll end up with `index2` whose format exactly matches `index1` except it only contains IDs from `read1`.

I am trying to implement the methods I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219141/searching-for-a-string-in-a-large-text-file-profiling-various-methods-in-pytho). But I'm stumbling on these two points: 1) I need to check IDs on every 4th line, but I need all of the data in `index1` (in order) because I have to write the associated 3 lines following the ID. 2) unlike that post, which is about searching for one string in a large file, I'm searching for a huge number of strings in another huge file.

Can some folks point me in some direction?  Maybe none of those 5 methods are ideal for this.  I don't know any information theory; we have plenty of RAM so I think holding the data in RAM for searching is the most efficient?  I'm really not sure.

Here a sample of what the `index` look like (IDs start with @M00347):

```
@M00347:30:000000000-BCWL3:1:1101:15589:1332 1:N:0:0
CCTAAGGTTCGG
+
CDDDDFFFFFCB
@M00347:30:000000000-BCWL3:1:1101:15667:1332 1:N:0:0
CGCCATGCATCC
+
BBCCBBFFFFFF
@M00347:30:000000000-BCWL3:1:1101:15711:1332 1:N:0:0
TTTGGTTCCCGG
+
CDCDECCFFFCB
```

`read1` looks very similar, but the lines before and after the '+' are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data of *index1* can fit in memory, the best approach is to do a single scan of this file and store all data in a dictionary like this:

```
    {"@M00347:30:000000000-BCWL3:1:1101:15589:1332 1:N:0:0":["CCTAAGGTTCGG","+","CDDDDFFFFFCB"],
     "@M00347:30:000000000-BCWL3:1:1101:15667:1332 1:N:0:0":["CGCCATGCATCC","+","BBCCBBFFFFFF"], 
     ..... }
```

Values can be stored as formatted string as you prefer.
After this, you can do a single scan on *read1* and when an IDs is encountered you can do a simple lookup on the dictionary to retrieve needed data.